# Linked List addLast() method is not working as expected

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

As per the definition [addLast()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linkedlist-addlast-method-in-java/), the addLast() method is used to add element to the last of the list. But here in the following code that's not happening.

```
LinkedList<Integer> demo = new LinkedList<>();
demo.addLast(15);
demo.addFirst(1);
demo.add(10);
System.out.println(demo);
```

The output is

```
[1, 15, 10]
```

But as per the definition the output should have been

```
[1, 10, 15]
```

Because the addLast() method should be adding 15 to the last of the list. I'm not sure what exactly is the issue here.

Code snippet : [Code snippet](https://www.onlinegdb.com/ryxz-qQMew)

Comment: plus, in the future try not to link code from external websites. liking from github might sometimes be okay because you might want to give in depth view of a big project but in case of small projects try to avoid external linking. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addLast` adds an item at the end of the list - it doesn't mean it will remain at the end of list when additional items are added.

Let's track the code:

- you start with an empty list.
- `addLast(15)` will add 15 at the end of this list, so it's now [15]
- `addFirst(1)` will add 1 at the beginning of the list, so it's now [1, 15]
- `add(10)` will add 10 at the end of the list, so it's now [1, 15, 10]

Answer (score 1):

`addLast()` does add 15 to the end of the list, it transfers it from `[]` to `[15]`. Later you use `add()`, which appends another element to the end of the list (after `15`).

From the documentation of [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)):

> public boolean add(E e) Appends the specified element to the end of
> this list. This method is equivalent to addLast(E).

Answer (score 1):

well as Obvious as this can be the `add()` adds at the last of the list and return a boolean indicating that the addition was successful or not.

yet on the other hand the `addLast()` method adds on the last but its void method so it wont return you a boolean.

from [javaDoc of the addlast()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast(E))

> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
>
> This method is equivalent to add(E).

from the [javaDoc of the add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E))

> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
>
> This method is equivalent to addLast(E).

but one might prefer to use `add()` for multiple reasons:

- as mentioned the return value.
- the `add(int index, E element)` :
  which will add a certain element to certain index.

and from [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,%20E)) of the `add(int index, E element)`

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>
> Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

and this method will throw an

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

so thats being said all what you are doing is the following:

```
demo.addLast(15);//your list now looks like this 15-> null
```

where `15` is the head and the tail in this case.

```
demo.addFirst(1);/your list now looks like this 1->15->null
```

now you have `1` as the head/leading element and the `15` as tail/trailing element.

and finally for

```
demo.add(10);//your list now looks like this 1->15->10->null.
```

for further informations here is how the `addFirst` and `addLast` works in the background:

`addFirst` will call the `linkFirst`

```
private void linkFirst(E e) {
    final Node<E> f = first;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(null, e, f);
    first = newNode;
    if (f == null)
        last = newNode;
    else
        f.prev = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

`addLast()` will call the `linkLast`

```
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```

I highly suggest that you do an implementation so you could build a better understanding of the whole concept.
happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation would be the following:

When you do `demo.addLast(15)` considere your list is empty, so you just have `[15]` after that you did `demo.addFirst(1)`, according the definition it is going to insert at start, so you have [1, 15], at last you did demo.add(10), it insert at final  so    you have `[1, 15, 10]`, when you print it will be `[1, 15, 10]`.